# asp.net code first migration seeding

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use EF 6 with migrations and seeding which works well most of the time.
it's the first time I use it and I have a problem with the seeding.

I have Tables stored in my database (wooden tables) and this is the starting point into my domain model so I create and add all stuff in the seeding and add them to the table. if i add additional properties or relations to other database tables the update-database works great and adds the new stuff to the database. It says also "runnig seeding" but never updates my existing tables! I always have to delete the database and run the update-database again to add the new stuff to the existing data even if I use:

```
context.Tables.AddOrUpdate(newTable);
```

Is there a way to force the seeding method to update them?

I try again.
The seeding methode does not update existing content.
You add a person:

```
new Person
{
    ID = 1,
    Name = "Smith"
}
```

now run the seeding methode.
Then add additional data to the person

```
new Person
{
    ID = 1,
    Name = "Smith",
    Prename = "John"
}
```

Seed again and your Person on the database will not be updated!

My workaround now is, delete the database and seed again.
DropAndCreateIfModelChanges does not work, because the model does not change, only the seeding.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't understand your problem exactly. Seeding of data is your responsibility, entity framework can't do anything with it. Just write proper code in `Seed` method of your `DbMigrationsConfiguration` class descedant.

Then you can trigger `Seed` method execution with use of `update-database` command in your package manager console. Also it will be called, when `DbContext` is used first time, so you can just restart your application pool as alternative.